# ASP.NET Core + Client Side Validation: No data-val-* attributes are generated if ViewBag and Model has same property name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation, viewbag, client-side-validation

I realized in ASP.NET Core 2.2 that no data-val-* attributes are generated if ViewBag and Model has the same property name (in my case it is about the propery "Title"). Because of missing data-val-* attributes client side validation does not work.

This is my Model:

```
public class ActivityModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

This is my View:

```
@model ActivityModel

@{ ViewBag.Title = "This is my title"; }  

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Activities"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}

@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

The ViewBag.Title property is used in _layout.cshtml to display the current title name.

If I either change the ViewBag or Model property name to something else data-val-* attributes are generated and client side validation works.

From the technical perspective what is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't figure out the exact reason of why this happening I can suggest you a few workarounds. The obvious one is to assign `ViewBag` values after rendering inputs

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Activities"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
} 

@{ ViewBag.Title = "This is my title"; }
```

Or you can make use of `input` [tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2) since it doesn't suffer from this problem

```
 <input asp-for="Title" />
 <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
```

**Might be interesting**

You can disable adding client validation attributes by setting `ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled` to `false` within razor view (this is pretty obvious)

```
@{
    ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
}
```

If for some reason you need to render more then 1 `input` for the same property with validation the following code

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
```

will render no validation for second `input`

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Title field is required." id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="Activity">
<input class="text-box single-line" id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="Activity">
```

This happens because the renderer tracks rendered properties and prevent adding validation more than once for the same property. The properties are tracked by `ViewContext.FormContext` so it is possible to control this behavior. Before adding validation attributes the renderer check if property was rendered by calling `ViewContext.FormContext.RenderedField(propertyName)` and if it renders a property it calls `ViewContext.FormContext.RenderedField(propertyName, true)` to mark property as rendered. But you can call this method with `false` like this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
@{
    ViewContext.FormContext.RenderedField("Title", false);
}
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
```

which gives the following result

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Title field is required." id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="Activity">
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Title field is required." id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="Activity">
```